# Socket io - method for handling users on the server

Tags: javascript, node.js, socket.io

In my application, I store users in my database. I'm implementing a messaging system using Socket Io and node, and I'm trying to create a method to efficiently handle users.

The goal is be able to send a message/event to a specific user (using their **socket id**). Every user should be connected to the socket server as soon as they initially load the application.

Here are the two options to solve this problem:

**Option 1:**

```
var users = []

io.on('connection', (socket) > {
   // Push user to array when connecting (include their user id as well as socket id)
   users.push({userId: 'ID FROM DB', socketId: socket.id})
})
```

This option stores all users in an array on the **server** with their corresponding Id and socket id. This means when sending a message to a user, the following code would be run:

```
// find user to send event to by searching existing array of user objects
let user = users.find((u) => u.userId = uid)
// send message to specific user
socket.to(user.userId).emit("send message", data)
```

**Option 2**:

```
io.on('connection', (socket) > {
   // Join a room with the name of the users unique id. User id would be passed in from the client
   socket.join(userId)
})
```

With option 2, no array is required to store users, instead they join a room with their own unique user id as soon as they connect.

When sending a message to a specific user, the code would look like the following for this option.

```
// Send to users personal room with the name being their user Id
io.to(userId).emit("send message", data)
```

Is there any issues with each of these options. Is one perhaps inefficient compared to the other? With option 2, could there be the possibility of having too many rooms, and could option 1 be problematic due to the size of the array becoming incredibly large if dozens of users connect to the server? Thanks.

Comment: Personally i like option 2 more, this is the way im using it. there are a few benefits, 1. you keep your server stateless (its good if you need to run more instances or multiple cors, you can also use redis this way). 2. if the user is connected with multiple devices, the message will appear on all of them. 3. you dont use big array in memory and its easier to just put the user id in the io.to(userId).emit()..

Comment: @ElnaHaim Ok thank you, however are there potentially any issues when using this method when scaling up? Perhaps related to performance and efficiency? Thanks.

Comment: im running this configuration on a platform with a lot of traffic, and i didnt face any performance issues. socket.io lets us use rooms out of the box, and it handles it pretty good. when we scaled up (running the server on multiple instances) we added redis adapter and its working good. (https://socket.io/docs/v4/redis-adapter).  this set up is better for scaling up, because then the server is stateless

Comment: @ElnaHaim That’s awesome! If I were to use option 1, and keep state on the server, would using a redis data structure to store the user data instead of just a plain JavaScript array be the best option when it comes to scaling? Would this be a scalable solution ?

Comment: Yes, you can use the redis adapter anyway in any one of the options. its very easy to implement and you can test it by creating a free user in the redis cloud https://redis.com/try-free/

Comment: @ElnaHaim Thanks for your help. So just to recap, option 2 is likely the better option and is scalable using methods such as the redis adapter. Option 1 is also possible, as you could use redis to store all the users and their socket id's on the server (instead of just a plain javascript array like the code in my question uses). This method is also scalable. Both the options are scalable. Is this correct? Thanks.

Comment: @ElnaHaim Sorry to repeat myself, however is my comment above correct? Thanks.

Comment: both options are scaleable if you are using redis. the second option will be easier for you to implement, because you just name the room as the user id.. also it will send notification to all devices connected to the same room (one user login with desktop and mobile).

Comment: @ElnaHaim Ok but if I were to use option 1, to make it scalable,  instead of using a normal JavaScript array, I’d use a redis store to record all the socket ids, and then just use the specific socket ids  when sending events to users. This is the scalable method for option 1 right ?

Comment: yes it is a scalable method for option 1.

Comment: @ElnaHaim Perfect thank you.